# multi-match search query clause limits

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a multi-match query as shown below with fields and query. (Elastic search 7.0)

```
GET users_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19",
      "fields": ["users.id",  "users.org", "users.email", "users.name", "posts.id"], 
      "operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "size": 25, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "posts.id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Sometimes when my query has more terms, I get `Query contains too many nested clauses; maxClauseCount is set to 1024` error even when 19*5 < 1024. Are there any other clauses which comes into play while calculating the limit. Is this because of ngrams?

index settings

```
"users": {
  "properties": {
    "organization": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false,
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "norms": false,
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "norms": false,
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false,
      "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "ngram_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": "3",
      "max_gram": "7"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The way you've specified your query (with best_fields and `and` operator), you are expecting **ALL query terms** to be present in at least one field. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: not really @Val, does that lead to other options to reduce the clause count?

Comment: Maybe show a real query and what the expected use case is.

Comment: @Val this is the real query with dummy query terms (in real scenario it would be ~ 5 terms of max 50 chars each) and the expectation is to find docs for the terms in a set of fields. Eventually, I don't need all terms to be in at-least one of the field. However, for sometime I need to make it consistent with my RDBMS like query results.

Answer (score 0):

Your multimatch query is the problem. 19 terms across 5 fields already produce 95 clauses, and depending on how the analysis of the text fields is set up, this can further multiply.

Ti improve it you can use should:

```
> "bool": {
>     "should": [
>       {"match": {"users.id": "1"}},
>       {"match": {"users.org": "1"}},
>       ...
>     ],
>     "minimum_should_match": 19   }
```

Or, if your server is large enough you can increase **maxClauseCount** from elastic config.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on how analysis of the text fields could add up to the limit.

Comment: if they are indexes as keyword, text https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html